# How to auto unchecked all checkbox if click another checkbox in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am angular2 beginner. I am creates a section hide and show using one common checkbox. On checked this checkbox show another checkbox list and unchecked hide the these checkbox list.

But problem is if I am checked checkbox list and then hide the this section and again checked so show already checked but I am try to unchecked all. If list is checked so on click common checkbox so this list is unchecked.

html code this :-

```
<form [formGroup] = "group">
<p>
  <md-checkbox (change)="form()" [(ngModel)]="good" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >Show/Hide and cheecked and unchecked</md-checkbox>
</p>

<div *ngIf="*ngIf="isVisible"" formArrayName="check">
  <span  *ngFor="let test of tests; let i = index" formGroupName="{{i}}">
     <md-checkbox formControlName="{{test.value}}" [checked] = "test.status" >{{test.display}}</md-checkbox>
   </span>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
tests:any = [
 { value: '1', display: 'One', status: 'false'},
 { value: '2', display: 'Two', status: 'false'},
 { value: '3', display: 'Three', status: 'false'},
 { value: '4', display: 'Four', status: 'false'}
]

isVisible:any;
good: string;
form() {
  let all: FormArray = new FormArray([]);
  for (let i = 0; i < this.tests.length; i++) {
    let fg = new FormGroup({});
    fg.addControl((this.tests[i].value).status, new FormControl(false))
    all.push(fg)
  }

  if(!this.isVisible) {
   this.group.get('tests').enable();
  } else {
   this.group.get('tests').disable();
  }
  this.isVisible = this.good;
}
```

Please tell us how to done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at this plunker example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/KeicXhLFs6h5uxBolMuD?p=preview

In app.ts:

```
update(index) {
    var currentState = this.options[index].val;
    for(let i = 0; i < this.options.length; i++) {
        this.options[i].val = false;
    }
    this.options[index].val = !currentState;
}
```

Update function will get current state of the checkbox before setting all to false. After this the clicked checkbox will be updated with the opposite. This way you will also be able to uncheck the checkbox.

Hope this helps.